# How can I access the Google Analytics dataLayer Variable in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, aurelia

I'm using the webpack with typescript combo for aurelia and want to know how I can push to the global dataLayer variable provided by google analytics in Aurelia classes?

When I try to log it I get:
Cannot find name 'dataLayer’.

but when I log it in the console of my browser, dataLayer exists

Any idea on how I can expose it?

```
console.log(window.dataLayer);

@inject(AppState, AuthService, SetupGuide, Endpoint.of('api'), 
DialogService, EventAggregator, Router)
export class Smoke {}
```

I know with webpack you can use shimming via:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
})
```

Is this possible also with the dataLayer variable?  I need to be able to update the dataLayer variable so I can setup Enhanced Ecommerce tracking.

**UPDATE:  I've also tried:**

```
(<any>window).dataLayer = (<any>window).dataLayer || [];
```

Does throw a type error: "Error: Can't resolve 'dataLayer'"

I need to be able to get access to the google analytics global variable and am not sure why this doesn’t work or how to expose it for ES6.

I'm using webpack and typescript and have added it to my index.ejs as follows:

```
<body aurelia-app="main">
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-okoko" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>
   (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
   new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
       j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
   'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
   })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ookok');
</script>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

There is no script tag that loads the app. Aurelia binds to body element.  This is my entire index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><%- htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.title %></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png?v=2">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png?v=5" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#34274f">
    <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#34274f">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#34274f">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">  
    <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.ENV === 'local') { %>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./src/main.css' type='text/css'>
     <% } %>
    <!-- imported CSS are concatenated and added automatically -->
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app="main">
    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-ookok" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <script>
       (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
       new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
       j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=false;j.src=
       'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
       })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ookok');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sample code that uses the variable:

```
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';
import {AppState} from '../../resources/global/appState';

@inject(AppState, Router)
export class Sample {
   attached(){
     console.log(dataLayer);
   }
}
```

Comment: When is window.dataLayer being set? Maybe after you are trying to call it? Can you not just access the window object in your class?

Comment: @2pha I can access the window object in my class, but trying (<any>window).dataLayer = (<any>window).dataLayer || []; 

Does throw a type error: "Error: Can't resolve 'dataLayer'"

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use npm package like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-analytics

Comment: @StanislavMayorov the only problem with that is that it is not for google tag manager, it is for google analytics.  Any idea how we can make it work for tag manager?

Comment: You need to create `dataLayer` _before_ you load the script.

Comment: @AluanHaddad that really shouldn't be necessary.  By default GTM loads async.

Comment: @JasonBiondo exactly and so does your app. Since you haven't shown any code that manipulators it, it's difficult to tell

Comment: Please update your question with the script tag that loads your app in addition to the code that uses the variable. Currently there isn't enough context

Comment: @AluanHaddad I've updated with a sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust your code as follows. Update your `main.ts` file so that it looks like

```
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  // ...
}

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

declare global {
  interface Window {
    // TODO: replace this with a more specific type based on usage
    dataLayer: any[];
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** The Aurelia specific code in the snippet above exits only to provide context. This answer is answer is also not specific to Webpack but rather applies to any TypeScript project using modules.

From here on you just access it by referencing `window.dataLayer`. The initialization code as well as the global declaration could be moved into a separate file and you could wrap it up in a service which acts as a proxy for the global if you wish to.

Comment: Your solution worked great.  I've now set it up globally and am able to use it throughout my app by just calling window.dataLayer

Comment: I'm really glad this worked for you. Would you mind marking it as the accepted answer? I'll happily add more explanation.

Comment: How do I do that?  I upvoted and gave you the bounty.

Comment: Click on the check mark below the vote counter. But anyway, no worries, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `externals` property in webpack config.

webpack.config.js

```
externals: {
  dataLayer: 'dataLayer'
}
```

yourSource.js

```
import dataLayer from 'dataLayer';
```

index.html

```
<body aurelia-app="main">
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-okoko" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>
   (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
   new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
       j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
   'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
   })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ookok');
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Throws: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'dataLayer'.

Comment: @JasonBiondo the GTM script doesn't register itself as a UMD, CommonJS, AMD, or System.register module, so this approach isn't going to work.